# Serialize a third-party struct

Tags: c#, serialization, struct

I'm writing a simple graphics application (using Cairo). I have the following base class:

```
[Serializable()]
public abstract class Shape : ICairoDrawable
{
    public PointD Start { get; set; }
    public PointD End { get; set; }

    public Color Filling { get; set; }
    public Color Outline { get; set; }

    public Shape(PointD start, PointD end, Color outline, Color fill)
    {
        Filling = fill;
        Outline = outline;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public abstract void Draw(Context context);
}
```

and many derived classes like

```
[Serializable()]
public class Line : Shape
{
    public Line(PointD start, PointD end, Color outline, Color fill)
        : base(start, end, outline, fill)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(Context context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When trying to serialize (using BinaryFormatter) a list of shapes created at runtime, I ran into the following problem: `PointD` is a struct defined and highly used in the Cairo library, so I can neither add `Serializable` attribute directly to it, nor derive from it and use my own struct. Same goes for `Color`.

So, what are the possible workarounds?

Comment: Implement custom serialization in your class as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does this mean that I need to add private serializable members which will hold the same data as the ones in question? And copy these data back and forth with custom `[OnSerializing()]` methods?

Comment: You should be able to get away with Implementing the ISerializable Interface. A good example is in the link above.