# Making a third-party struct serialisable

Tags: c#, serialization, struct

So basically I'm using a third party library which has a particular Struct which I need to serialise.

The actual struct is heavily used by other functions which I need, so I can't just rewrite it myself from scratch.

I can't extend the struct itself (because structs can't be extended) and the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361345/serialize-a-third-party-struct) won't really work for me as I'm using it in a ton of classes which I can't stay implementing serialisation manually for.

Anything I can do ?

Comment: Which serialization method are you using?

Comment: The built in Binary Serialisation thing. The one which requires you to put [Serializable] on top of everything

Comment: Ok, then you can use [serialization surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SerializationSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) to serialize instances of a type that was not designed for serialization.

Comment: Did not know about these. Thanks. I'll give it a try and see how it goes.